# Calculating median value from a list of numbers

Tags: beginner, rust, statistics

I am learning Rust and I would like to get some feedback around my solution to calculate the median value from a list of integers.

I believe the logic is correct as my tests pass, but I'm concerned the right types and if I coded "the Rust way".

```rust
use std::f32;

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    v.push(5);
    v.push(6);
    v.push(7);
    v.push(8);
    v.push(9);

    println!("{:?}", get_median(v)); // 7
    
    v = Vec::new();
    v.push(5);
    v.push(6);
    v.push(7);
    v.push(8);
    v.push(9);
    v.push(10);
    println!("{:?}", get_median(v)); // 7.5
    
    v = Vec::new();
    v.push(6);
    v.push(5);
    v.push(10);
    v.push(7); 
    v.push(9);
    v.push(8);
    println!("{:?}", get_median(v)); // 7.5
    
    v = Vec::new();
    v.push(-2);
    v.push(-9);
    v.push(-4);
    v.push(-1); 
    v.push(0);
    v.push(6);
    println!("{:?}", get_median(v)); // -1.5
}

fn get_median(numbers: Vec<i32>) -> f32 {
    let mut v = numbers;
    v.sort();
    let length = v.len() as f32;

    if length%2.0 == 1.0 {
        let index = length as usize / 2;
        v[index] as f32
    } else {
        let index = length as usize / 2;
        let lower_mid: usize = index - 1;
        let higher_mid: usize = index;

        (v[lower_mid] + v[higher_mid]) as f32 / 2.0 
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have to consider the case where the vector is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Some basics

1. You don't need to bring `f32` into scope, it's in there by default.
2. Use `rustfmt` on your code.
3. Use a linter like `clippy`.

#### Use initializer functions

You don't need to push your elements on a `Vec` one by one. Use `Vec::from()`. Or, even better, use the `vec!` macro.

#### Use a cargo project

Develop your project as a cargo crate. It will make the organization of tests and possible dependencies much easier.

#### Use unit tests

Use cargo's test suite to assert that your code is working.

#### Useless conversions

You convert `Vec::len()` from `usize` to `f32` just to convert it back to `usize` again.

#### Write generic code

You can generalize your code by using generics and appropriate traits, so that it accepts other numeric iterables.

#### Remember edge cases

As pointed out by @G.Sliepen, you might also want to consider the case, where the vector is empty.

#### Suggested:

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "median"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

[dev-dependencies]
once_cell = "*"
```

`src/lib.rs`:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

pub fn median<T>(items: &[T]) -> f64
where
    T: Add<Output = T> + Copy + Into<f64> + Ord,
{
    let mut items: Vec<T> = items.to_vec();

    if items.is_empty() {
        return 0.0;
    }

    items.sort();
    let len = items.len();

    if len % 2 == 0 {
        (items[len / 2] + items[len / 2 - 1]).into() / 2.0
    } else {
        items[len / 2].into()
    }
}
```

`tests/test.rs`:

```rust
use median::median;
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

static MEDIANS: Lazy<[(f64, Vec<i32>); 5]> = Lazy::new(|| {
    [
        (7.0, vec![5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
        (7.5, vec![5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
        (7.5, vec![6, 5, 10, 7, 9, 8]),
        (-1.5, vec![-2, -9, -4, -1, 0, 6]),
        (0.0, vec![]),
    ]
});

#[test]
fn test_median() {
    for (nominal, numbers) in MEDIANS.iter() {
        assert_eq!(*nominal, median(numbers));
    }
}
```